# Two fractions with the same size

Tags: fractions, displaystyle

Can anyone tell me how I can make  `$A=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{b}}$` look the same?
So I want `$a$` to be on the same height as the other denominator.

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
  $A=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}+1}$\\ 
  $A=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{\frac{b}{t}}+1}$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I get the bottom of denominator `a` at the same height as the bottom of `a+b`. Can you please better explain the issue?

Comment: It is not $a+b$, but \frac{a}{b}.

Comment: Use the following to see the problem:                 \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

$A=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}+1}$\$A=\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{\frac{b}{t}}+1}$

\end{document}

Comment: I don't really get what you want, could you add a sketch?

Comment: It's still not clear what you are asking. Complicated fractions should be set in a displayed equation and not inline; with `\dfrac` or `\tfrac` (that require `\usepackage{amsmath}`), you can ensure the same size for the letters.

Comment: Add in a `\vphantom{<d>}` in the denominators of the fractions with the smaller height, where `<d>` is the denominator with the maximal height.

Comment: example of the problem: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=67mivk&s=5

Comment: @egreg, how should I edit my code to get it right? I loaded that package already.

Comment: @marc, \vphantom lets things disappear?

Comment: @user31951 Yes, `\vphantom{<stuff>}` gives a box with zero width and the same height as `<stuff>`.

Comment: If you compare your `a` from the left frac with the `1` from the right frac, you can see that they are in fact, on the same height (and in the same font size). The (inner) `a/b` frac is similar to the outer fracs (e.g. `1/a`) vertically centered and one style smaller. To change this, use `\[\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\frac{a}{b}+1}\]` or `\[\frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{\dfrac{a}{b}+1}\]`. Or do you want to achieve [something like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QTnDA.png)?

Comment: or do you mean something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zz86W.png)....

Comment: Or maybe you just want something simple like this: `A = \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{(a/b)+1}'??

Comment: As the comments make clear, it's really not clear what is wanted here.